# Meaning of Func<object, bool>(p => true)

Tags: c#, delegates

I saw this line of code:

```
var myFilter= val1 ? (Func<Person, bool>)(person=> true) : (person=> person.IsValid);
```

What does this part means?:

```
(Func<Person, bool>)(person=> true)
```

Then, the `myFilter` variable is being used to filter some data from a table...

```
return ctx.Persons.Where(myFilter).ToList();
```

What happens when `val1` is true and the first part of the conditional  `(Func<Person, bool>)(person=> true)` is selected?

Comment: It's casting the lambda to a specific delegate type.  This is required because of the use of `var` and the conditional operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Where` method takes a parameter of type `Func<T, bool>` - this is essentially a function that takes a `T` (in this case, `Person`) as a parameter, and returns a `bool`.  The `Where` method evaluates this function for each object in the source list and filters to only those that result in `true`.

The delegate `person => true` defines a method that takes a `Person` as a parameter and *always* returns true, regardless of the `Person` object.  When used in a `Where` clause, this will never filter out anything and returns the original set of items.  (The cast to `Func<T, bool>` is required because of the use of `var` - the compiler can't determine the type of an anonymous delegate without a hint.)

So this code:

```
var myFilter = val1 ? (Func<Person, bool>)(person => true) : (person => person.IsValid);
return ctx.Persons.Where(myFilter).ToList();
```

does the same thing as this:

```
if (val1)
{
    return ctx.Persons.ToList();
}
else
{
    return ctx.Persons.Where(person => person.IsValid).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In such case the expression passed to `Where` returns `true` always - for any `Person` passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

For the conditional operator to compile, the two expressions need to have the same type. Lambdas have unique types, so two lambdas don't have the same type. By casting (at least) one of these lambdas to a `Func<Person, bool>`, the common type of the two expression can be determined to be `Func<Person, bool>` by implicit conversion of the other lambda to the Func type.

So `myFilter` is now either the function that always returns true, or if `val1` is false, actually does some filtering when used as a Where clause.

Comment: Technically it's called the conditional operator.  It just happens to be the only ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks, I'm coming from a C++ background, where it's ternary, afaik

Comment: Yes! The same could be achieved with multiple statements like this: `Func<Person, bool> myFilter; if (val1) { myFilter = person=> true; } else { myFilter = person => person.IsValid; }`. Another option is to capture (close over) the `val1`, as in this simple example: `Func<Person, bool> myFilter = person => val1 || person.IsValid;`